# Logical Subtlety in Division Algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Let $\sigma$ be the $m$-cycle $(a_1~a_2...a_m)$. Deduce that $|\sigma| = m$.

Here is my solution, with questions about the correctness of this solution scattered throughout:

I already proved that $\sigma^i(a_k) = a_{k+i}$, where $k \in \{1,...,m\}$ and $k+i$ is replaced by the least positive residue when $k+i$ is divided by $m$. Hence, by this composition formula $\sigma^m (a_k) = a_{k+m}$. By the division algorithm, there exist unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $k+m = qm + r$, where $r \in \{1,...,m-1\}$ is the least positive residue we are seeking. Now clearly $q = 1$ and $r=k$ are choices that satisfy the equation. My question is, does this imply that these are in fact the $q$ are $r$ guaranteed by the division algorithm? It seems that the uniqueness part, in particular, implies that $q = 1$ and $r=k$.

If this is the case, then I can say $\sigma^m(a_k) = a_k$ for all $k \in \{1,...,m\}$, implying $|\sigma| \le m$. Now, suppose that $|\sigma| = d \le m$. Then $\sigma^d(a_k) = a_k$ for all $k$. This means $k$ is the least positive residue, or, in other words, $k+d = q'm + r'$, where $r' = k$. Hence $d = q'm$. This is a contradiction unless $q' = 1$, because $q' < 0$ would imply $|\sigma| < 0$ and $q' > 0$ would imply $d > m$.

First of all, does any of this sound correct? Second, is there a better/cleaner way of thinking about this?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You are asking this question as if we were behind your shoulder reading the same book as you do. Provide some context.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I don't quite understand your remark. I thought I provided enough context. I put the question I am currently working on in the yellow box and gave my solution to the problem; and then throughout my post my inserted questions about my solution.

Comment: what is your definition for the order of an element?

Comment: @AlanWang My book defines the order of some element $x$ as that smallest natural number $n$ for which $x^n = e$, where $e$ is the identity of whichever group we are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may make your life simpler if you

- write the cycle as $\sigma = (a_{0}, a_{1}, \dots, a_{m-1})$,
- regard the indices as integers modulo $m$,
- note that $\sigma$ acts as $a_{i} \mapsto a_{i+1}$,
- so that $\sigma^{k}$ acts as $a_{i} \mapsto a_{i+k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the order of $\sigma$ is $n$.
This means that $\sigma^n=e$.
Hence $\sigma^n(a_k)=e(a_k)=a_k$ for $k=1,2,\dots,m$.
You have verified that $a_{k+n\bmod m}=a_k$.
Thus $k+n\equiv k\bmod m$, which implies $n\equiv 0 \bmod m$.
Since $n$ is the smallest positive integer which satisfies this equation by definition of order. we conclude that $n=m.$